# VSPackage using C++, How to get current working projects directory in visual studio?

Tags: c++, vspackage

I'm developing my own vspackage using C++. And I need to get current working project directory. But I don't know how to do it, all I can find in google is using C#.

I found that "DTE" may be the key to do this. But how to get dte instance? There is no "GetService", and there is no "EnvDTE" namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered a similar inquiry a couple years back in the MSDN [VS Extensibilty Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7146a5ff-2286-43be-9e79-024b71d68c76/translate-c-code-to-c?forum=vsx).